# Why image path is not resolved by require() when passed as prop in NuxtJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, nuxt.js

In my NuxtJS project I have a component that recieves an image path as a prop. I tried passing it directly to `:src="imageAddress"` but it neither resolve nor throws an error. Then I tried to use this path inside `require()` to resolve it properly. But I get this Nuxt error: Cannot find module '~/assets/icons/crown.png'. The path is correct and I tested that by placing an `img` element directly in `index.vue`. Do you have any idea why this happens?
This is how my code is structured:

```html
pages/index.vue
<template>
  <ChildComponent image-address="~/assets/icons/crown.png" />
</template>

___________________________________________________________________

components/ChildComponent.vue
<template>
  <img v-if="imageAddress.length" :src="require(imageAddress)">
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ChildComponent',
  props: {
    imageAddress: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: ''
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: no need for require just add url directly#

Comment: @ToufiqAhmed I mentioned in the question that I have done that. it doesn't resolve. it is placed inside src as it is ~/assets/icons/crown.png.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to make method in ChildComponent:

```
getUrl (img)  {
  return require(`~/assets/icons/${img}.png`);
}
```

then in template:

```html
<img :src="getUrl(imageAddress)" alt="" />
```

Comment: This worked, thanks, I used a computed property instead of a method.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share what worked for me. Since using `require` gives undefined error. I used `import` instead.

```js
import imageAddress from '~/asset/icons/crown.png';
```

```js
<template>
  <ChildComponent :image-address="imageAddress" />
</template>
```

Comment: `require` is indeed for old build tools (Webpack).