# Vue require dynamic image

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I've created this Vue component and pass it an icon path.

```
<CTA type="primary" icon="~/assets/phone/img/icons/share.svg" icon-alt="share">
  Primary CTA
</CTA>
```

My setup method returns the following

```
setup(props) {
  return {
   ctaIcon: props.icon,
  }
},
```

So `ctaIcon` equals `~/assets/phone/img/icons/share.svg`.

When I try to use `ctaIcon` in the template, this works

```
<img :src="require('~/assets/phone/img/icons/share.svg')" />
```

But this doesn't work

```
<img :src="require(ctaIcon)" />
```

I get the following error `Cannot find module '~/assets/phone/img/icons/share.svg'`

How to get it to work properly ?

Comment: Try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68652147/how-to-load-a-dynamic-path-in-my-image-tag-in-nuxt/68652472#68652472) for solution

Comment: As told before, please make the effort of a quick search.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load a dynamic path in my image tag in Nuxt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68652147/how-to-load-a-dynamic-path-in-my-image-tag-in-nuxt)

Comment: Not really, because I wanted to pass the full path of my image as prop and just `require` the whole prop but it doesn't work, I followed Salivino's advice in the end, create a computed property with `require(`~assets/${props.icon}`)` and pass `phone/img/icons/share.svg` as prop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `computed property` to calibrate the url of asset as follows:

```html
<script>
export default {
  props: ["ctaIcon"],
  computed: {
    mIconURL() {
      return require(`~/assets/icons/${this.ctaIcon}.png`);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Then in your code you can directly use the computed property as a variable:

`<img :src="mIconURL" />`

If you have multiple icons whose paths need to be resolved then, you could even create a `method` instead of a `computed property` that takes in an icon name as argument. The icon name can then be pass dynamically to the method from the tag level as follows:

`<img :src="mIconURL(this.ctaIcon)" />`

Comment: The thing is, I would like to pass the full icon path as prop (e.g. icon="~/assets/phone/img/icons/share.svg") to allow more flexibility. I've tried this approach `const ctaIcon = computed(() => require(`${props.icon}`))` but it doesn't work either. Why isn't working if I don't hardcode a path ?

Comment: If you like to pass the full path, I would suggest keep the `~/assets/` constant in the `computed` property as that will not change right? Rest of the path like `phone/img/icons/share.svg` can be interpolated in the string in the `computed` property.

Comment: You can prepare img path const img = this.ctaIcon.split('/').slice(2, this.ctaIcon.length).join('/'))  return require(`~/assets/${img}`); so you can pass full icon path