# Using local files with dynamic names for img src in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I recently moved from React to Vue and I have a hard time understanding how local icons/images work in Vue. I tried:

```
<img v-bind:src="'@/public/' + product.img" /> 
<img v-bind:src="'/../../public/'+ product.img" /> 
<img v-bind:src="'../assets/'+ product.img" />
```

Yes images are both in public and src/assets and everything works fine if I use static src instead of :src

Comment: You might find my previous answer useful on how to bind images dynamically in vue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68665555/vue-require-dynamic-image/68665769#68665769). Just replace the `this.ctaIcon` with your icon name. Images from public folder can directly be accessed with `<img :src="/product.img" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make method (assuming product.img = imagename.png):

```
   methods: {
     getImg(img) {
       return require(`../assets/${img}`);
     }
   }
```

then in template call that method with passing img :

```
<img v-bind:src="getImg(product.img)" />
```

Comment: getting error in console like `LocateUs.vue:91 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`..
any solutions please..