# Dynamic image path not working in Require function : This relative module was not found

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am stuck on an error from the past 2 days on VueJs require function. I am trying to past a prop to the Home component and then display the image.

Home.vue

```
<template>
<BlogPost :post="welcomeScreen"/>
<BlogPost :post="post" v-for="(post,index) in sampleBlogPost" :key="index"/>
</template>

<script>
import BlogPost from '../components/BlogPost.vue'
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components:{
   BlogPost
  }
  ,
data(){
  return{
    welcomeScreen:{
      title:'Welcome',
      blogPost:'Test post',
      welcomeScreen: true,
      photo: 'coding',
    }
    ,
    sampleBlogPost: [
      {
        title: 'This is a filter title',
        blogHtml : 'This is a blog filter title',
        blogCoverPhoto: 'beautiful-stories'
      }
      ,
         {
        title: 'This is a filter title',
        blogHtml : 'This is a blog filter title',
        blogCoverPhoto: 'designed-for-everyone'
      }
    ]
  }
}
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.logo{
  max-width: 150px;
}
</style>
```

BlogPost.vue

```
<template>
 <div class="blog-wrappe">
     <div class="blog-content">
         <h2 v-if="post.welcomeScreen">{{post.title}}</h2>
         <h2 v-else>{{post.title}}</h2>
         <p v-if="post.welcomeScreen">{{post.blogPost}}</p>
         <p v-else>{{post.blogHtml}}</p>  
         <router-link class="link link-light" v-if="post.welcomeScreen" to="#">Login/Register <img src="@/assets/Icons/arrow-right-light.svg"></router-link>
         <router-link class="link link-light" v-else to="#">View the post</router-link>    
         <div class="blog-photo">
             
         <img v-if="post.welcomeScreen" :src="require('../assets/blogPhotos/${post.photo}.jpg')" alt="">
            <!-- <img v-else :src="require('../assets/blogPhotos/${post.blogCoverPhoto}.jpg')" alt=""> -->
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
name: 'BlogPost',
props:['post'],
data(){
    return {
        photo: this.post.photo
    }
}
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">


</style>
```

I am getting this error:

> This relative module was not found:
>
> ../assets/blogPhotos/${post.photo}.jpg in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/templateLoader.js??ref--6!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--0-1!./src/components/BlogPost.vue?vue&type=template&id=a2b18adc"

But when I remove '${post.photo}' and placed 'coding' it works fine.

Comment: Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68665555/vue-require-dynamic-image/68665769#68665769)

Comment: I tried your answer(make a method and return image path) but it doesn't, work also.

Comment: What error do you get after doing so? is it the same error as above?

Comment: 1. You have to use back-tick for string concatenation with javascript variables. ```:src="require(`../assets/blogPhotos/${post.photo}.jpg`)"``` This will solve your problem of not having the correct path since you can see that in the error you have shown does not have the value of the variable.
2. I am not sure how it goes with require, but i am 100% sure that importing does not let you use dynamic path since it resolves the path before runtime. Long story short import the files and decide at runtime which file to use.

Comment: @Salvino yes same error.

Comment: @Komi I can,t import the images because later I will load posts from firebase. Just create a dummy model as of now but it does not work and I am stuck on this for 4,5 days.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will resolve the string inside require to the string you want it to. As far as I am concerned it will not work most of the time, since if the full image path is different, require will not know what files to load.

But since you are lucky and your folder's path is constant require will load all the files from that folder ('assets/blogPhotos') and you can use them dynamically.

```html
<template>
 <div class="blog-wrappe">            
         <img v-if="post.welcomeScreen" :src="require(`../assets/blogPhotos/${post.photo}.jpg`)" alt="">
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'BlogPost',
    props: ['post'],
    data() {
      return {
        photo: this.post.photo || 'cover',
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Also if you have assets that have completely different paths, you can do something like this, this also has the added benefit, but it will have the added benefit of not loading unnecessary files from that folder, only the ones you need!

Take a look:

```html
<template>
 <div class="blog-wrappe">            
         <img v-if="post.welcomeScreen" :src="getPhotoUrl(post.photo)" alt="">
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  import coding from '../asset/blog/coding.jpg';
  import coding1 from '../pictures/photos/coding1.jpg';
  import coding2 from '../images/some/coding2.jpg';
  import coding3 from '../browse/image/coding3.jpg';

  export default {
    name: 'BlogPost',
    props: ['post'],
    methods: {
      getPhotoUrl(photoKey) {
        const availablePhotoUrlsMap = {
          coding,
          coding1,
          coding2,
          coding3
        }
        if (!availablePhotoUrlsMap.hasOwnProperty(photoKey)) {
          throw new Error(`photo with key ${photoKey} is not available`);
        }
        return availablePhotoUrlsMap[photoKey];
      }
    }
</script>
```