# vue - image Url as prop not showing image

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am passing `imageSrc` from `App.vue` to `HelloWorld.vue`, but the image doesn't show up.

App.vue

```
 <HelloWorld imageSrc="./assets/logo.png" />
```

HelloWORLD.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <img :src="imageSrc" alt="img" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    imageSrc: String,
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-hofstadter-bomkf?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:0-432

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue require dynamic image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68665555/vue-require-dynamic-image)

Comment: You are missing the `:` to denote a prop on your HelloWorld component. Try `<HelloWorld :imageSrc='"./assets/logo.png"' />` . Also note the extra quotes on the image src.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you and it's working:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <HelloWorld :imageSrc="logo" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";
import Logo from "./assets/logo.png";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      logo: Logo,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Working Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-haze-z3b7m?file=/src/App.vue:0-331

Answer (score 0):

Move your `assets` folder into public. It should work fine.

Here's the Demo [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-shirley-2g3ot?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

[From the docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling)

> Static assets placed in the public directory and referenced via absolute paths. These assets will simply be copied and not go through webpack.

To access the static assets with absolute path, you should keep assets in public folder.

Read the [documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling) for more info.