# Is there a way to reference the images in vue?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, single-page-application, vuejs3

I'm building a SPA using vue.js, I need to assign a div background-image referencing something in the following path:

[image: Vue project structure]

I'm trying to reference ***src/assets/img/firstCard.jpg*** but for some reason it doesn't shows the image, this is how I'm binding the image:

[image: vue image binding]

HTML:

```
 <a class="card">
    <div
      class="card__background"
      v-bind:style="secondCard">
    </div>
    <div class="card__content">
      <p class="card__category">Gratuita</p>
      <h3 class="card__heading">Ademas en diferentes plataformas.</h3>
    </div>
  </a>
```

JS:

```
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      thirdCard: {
        'background-image': require('@/assets/img/firstCard.jpg')
      },
      secondCard: {
        'background-image': require('@/assets/img/firstCard.jpg')
      },
      firstard: {
        'background-image': require('@/assets/img/firstCard.jpg')
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68652147/why-image-path-is-not-resolved-by-require-when-passed-as-prop-in-nuxtjs/68652472#68652472) for answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to make method or computed property:

```
getUrl (img)  {
  return require(`@/assets/img/${img}.jpg`);
}
```

then call that method in data object (for background-image you need to specify url):

```
data () {
  return {
    firstCard: {
      'background-image': `url(${this.getUrl('firstCard')})`
    } 
  }
},
```

Comment: it didn't work as I'm not using an img it's a div I tried the following ways:
JS:

`<script>
export default {
  name: 'CardGrid',
  data () {
    return {
      firstImage: { backgroundImage: require('@/assets/img/firstCard.jpg') }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    secondImage: () => {
      require('@/assets/img/firstCard.jpg')
    }
  }
}
</script>`
WAY 1 :

`<div
          class="card__background"
          @:style="{backgroundImage: secondImage()}">
        </div>`
WAY 2:
` <div
          class="card__background"
           @:style="firstImage">
        </div>`

Comment: Ok mate, i corrected answer, you can try now

Comment: Thank you @Nikola it's working now i had to create the scripts this way:

`<script>
export default {
  name: 'CardGrid',
  data () {
    return {
      firstImage: { 'background-image': this.getImageUrl('firstCard') }
      // secondImage: { 'background-image': this.getImageUrl('secondCard') },
      // thirdImage: { 'background-image': this.getImageUrl('thirdCard') }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getImageUrl: (image) => {
      const url = require(`@/assets/img/${image}.jpg`)
      return 'url('${url}')'
    }
  }
}
</script>`